# HTML to PDF Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, download, converters

I need to create a PDF that will contain employee CVs for an employer to download. The information that needs to go into the CV  e.g first_name, last_name etc needs to be extracted from the database and then I need to build the format of the CV with HTML and then make it possible to be downloaded as a PDF.

I know how to get the user info and build the HTML be not sure how to convert it to a PDF afterwards is there a good WordPress plugin to do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a Wordpress plugin that will do this, but take a look at the [mPDF library](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) for php.

Comment: I hope that you need to build such a function manually. Try some php functions and integrate them in the WP.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a little out of time for answering, I had the same problem some time ago and I didn't find any plugin for doing it. So what I did was integrate fpdf.

It is really easy. Just download the last version from [here](http://www.fpdf.org/), save it on one folder on your directory and include it on your function.php.

Then, you will be able to build an html string and generate the pdf file with it. Take a look at the tutorials on the fpdf page, they will be really useful for knowing what tags you will be able to use.

good luck!